# How to reference a range of cells containing monthnameshort in GETPIVOTDATA

Tags: excel-formula, pivot-table, date-range

I am trying to build a more agile and time limiting financial reporting tool.
In this proces I stumpled upon a problem that I can't seem to fix.

I am trying to get Year-to-date numbers by referencing a range of cells containing Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep

Formula that works for january only:

**=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Amount]";'Regnskab pr. mdr.'!$A$10;"[Dim GL Account Hierachy].[Parent GL Account]";"[Dim GL Account Hierachy].[Parent GL Account].&[1495 Nettoomsætning i alt]";"[Dim Posting Date].[MonthNameShort]";"[Dim Posting Date].[MonthNameShort].&[Jan]")**

Here I want to refence a range of cells containing the months I want (jan to sep)
I can't do it this simple:

=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Amount]";'Regnskab pr. mdr.'!$A$10;"[Dim GL Account Hierachy].[Parent GL Account]";"[Dim GL Account Hierachy].[Parent GL Account].&[1495 Nettoomsætning i alt]";"[Dim Posting Date].[MonthNameShort]";"[Dim Posting Date].[MonthNameShort].**&[Jan]:[Sep]")**

Does anybody know how to make this work?

(I might add that the pivot table, which i am trying to reference, is visible in the Sheet next to the report and also functions as a specification sheet to the different accounts for management to see).

Thanks a lot

Comment: post and ghost...?

Answer (score 0):

TMK - I don't know that you can create a range within GETPIVOTDATA. You can approach this in one of following ways.

First, I emulated your table by building a data model based on the two dim tables that you show as well as a DAX measure called Amount.  I placed a PowerPivot table at B3 in my worksheet, so all cell references used below are based on this.

[image: Setup]

**Treat your PivotTable as a Range**
You can make a formula that references the cell ranges from the pivot instead of going inside of the pivot.  Based on the piv table shown above, it would be this:

```
=SUM( (MONTH(DATEVALUE(C4:N4&"-0"))<=9) * (B5:B9="1495 Nettoomsætning i alt") * C5:N9 )
```

> I'm guessing at your layout; so you would need to fix the formula accordingly.

The `(MONTH(DATEVALUE(C4:N4&"-0"))<=9)` converts the MonthNameShort headers into date values by appending a year "2000" onto the back of them and then pulls out a Month Number. It then checks if it is 1 through 9. The next piece sees if the Parent GL Account = your target acct. This boolean matrix is then multiplied times your Amount matrix.

You can see from the SUM Forumula in cell L12 that it calculated it correctly.

**Use DAX**
You could create a measure that filters to your target dates. This is probably not what you want, but it might be OK and it is worth noting. Perhaps:

```
filtAmount := CALCULATE( [Amount], 'Dim Posting Date'[MonthNum] <= 9 )
```

And you can get it from your GETPIVOTDATA.

**Use CUBE functions with DAX**
As you are already using a PowerPivot data model and pivot table, you may be able to explore CUBE Functions.  [Here](https://macrordinary.ca/2020/08/19/cube-formulas-the-best-excel-formulas-youre-not-using/) is a very good article to get started.

This approach relies on a Slicer that has numerical data, so you would need a field such as **MonthNum** in your **Dim Posting Date** table and then you would need to use that as a slicer. This may not be what you are after either because, of course, you could do that with GETPIVOTDATA and simply use:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[Amount]";$A$10;
              "[Dim GL Hierarchy].[Parent GL Account]";"[Dim GL Hierarchy].[Parent GL Account].&[1495 Nettoomsætning i alt]")
```

But you may be able to apply your slicer so that it does not impact your table, but does impact your CUBE formula. This is possible through CUBE functions because they use a common data model called `"ThisWorkbookDataModel"`. This is an advantage over GETPIVOTDATA.

```
=CUBEVALUE( "ThisWorkbookDataModel";
            CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[Measures].[Amount]"),
            CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[Dim GL Hierarchy].[Parent GL Account].&[1495 Nettoomsætning i alt]");
            CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[Dim Posting Date].[MonthNameShort].[All]","Grand Total");
            Slicer_MonthNum )
```

This CUBE formula is based on a real slicer that I applied to the **another** pivot table.  I then deleted that pivot table, but not the slicer. So this Slicer is applied to the deleted pivot table and not the target pivot table. The slicer does not impact the target piv table as you can see here:

[image: slicer and piv table]

And, if you like, you can hide the slicer somewhere in the workbook, if you don't want people changing it.

You may be able to synthesize a slicer as a DAX measure.  I tried that but could not get it to work. A helpful video on that is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gi2TssWtjdY).